# Echo a image in cakephp after uploading it

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to echo an image after i upload to logos folder which is under the app folder. The uploading is working but the challenge that i have right now is to echo the image in the view. Below is my upload function and the view code

```
function uploadFile() {
$file = $this->data['Logo']['file'];
if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
$id = String::uuid();
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP.'logos'.DS.$id)) {
$this->request->data['Logo']['filename'] = $file['name'];
$this->request->data['Logo']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
$this->request->data['Logo']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
return true;
}
}
return false;
}
```

and for the view code, i using this code.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image(APP. 'logos' . DS. $logo['Logo']['filename']); ?>
```

Thanks you for your help you will provide.

Answer (score 2):

There is a .htaccess at `app folder`, which will not allow to access any content directly outside webroot folder. For ease of use, you should upload images inside webroot folder somewhere.